# python linux - display image with filename as viewer window title

Tags: python, linux, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

when I display an image with PIL Image it opens an imagemagick window but the title is some gibberish name like 'tmpWbfj48Bfjf'. How do I make the image filename to be the title of the viewer window?

Comment: If I recall correctly PIL saves the image to a temporary  file and then opens the viewer using that file. So the name you see **is** the filename, the one of the temporary file. If you don't want that, display the original with `subprocess.check_output([your_viewer_binary, original_image_name])`

Comment: what is 'your_viewer_binary' ? imagemagick bin ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the title attribute: `Image.show(title="Your Title Here" [...]`

From the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show):

> Image.show(title=None, command=None) Displays this image. This method
>   is mainly intended for debugging purposes.
>
> On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary PPM
>   file, and calls the xv utility.
>
> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the
>   standard BMP display utility to show it (usually Paint).
>
> Parameters:    title – Optional title to use for the image window, where
>   possible. command – command used to show the image

Comment: Thanks, On the paper this should be the right answer but it doesn't work for me. ..

Comment: For me also does not show. Tested on mac os