# Python PIL: How does one change file name in viewer?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In python I use PIL to view images for testing. I understand that when I use
im.show(), a random name is assigned to the image and then Paint(Win10) displays the image. I reviewed other questions and saw the following:[python linux - display image with filename as viewer window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546806/python-linux-display-image-with-filename-as-viewer-window-title)

The part I thought I understood was to use the following:
im.show(title="ABCD"). It does not change the displayed name of the image.
How do I go about go about changing the file name when I use my_image.show() in Python?

Comment: From the documentation for `.show()`: "title – Optional title. Not all viewers can display the title."  The implementation for this method is entirely different on each supported platform.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that might be the case. I am now writing an OpenCv display function that gives me the power to: zoom, pan, display coordinates, pixel value, and a few others.